# Bootstrap button not displaying inline with container element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a simple banner for a website using Bootstrap CSS and after centering text within the banner, I would like a button to be displayed inline with it.  However, after I create the button, it does not display inline with the centered text within the button.

HTML:

```
<div id="idea_banner">  
    <div class="container">
        <b>Got an idea? Tell us about it!</b>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Give us an idea</a>

    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#idea_banner {
  background: #4B91FB;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:90px;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
}

.container b {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-top:35px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:22px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.container a {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

I'm not really sure if this is a Bootstrap issue or not.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is not button in your HTML!

Comment: @RahulDesai I'm actually using a Bootstrap button as in the '<a>' class "btn btn-success btn-large"

Comment: Please find the answer below and mark it as accepted if it solves your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening because you had displayed `b` as `block` in your CSS. Change it to `inline` to get it into a single line.

Also, remove `float: left` for `.container a` and add `text-align: center` for `.container`.

By the way, `<b>` tag is not recommended. If you need an element to wrap the text, use `<p>` instead.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
#idea_banner {
  background: #4B91FB;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:90px;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.container b {
  display: inline;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-top:35px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:22px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.container a {
  display:inline;
  /*float:left;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div id="idea_banner">  
    <div class="container">
        <b>Got an idea? Tell us about it!</b>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Give us an idea</a>

    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect!  I knew it had something to do with the 'display' property and the wrapping.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @RahusDesai Only 1 minor detail I noticed where the 'margin-top' property isn't actually pushing the 'b' tag isn't actually floating from the top.

Comment: I actually did some research and found that using 'top' instead of 'margin-top' and adding 'position:relative' will actually fix this problem.  Anyways, thank you for your solution.

Comment: @JeffP. That would be another question on StackOverflow. Please post it and link me to it. :)

Comment: Found it, see my answer above.  Thank you!